# How to convert django variable into json in template properly

Tags: django, json, django-templates

I am using [django-jsonify](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jsonify/0.2.1) to convert django variable into json in javascript, and it returns such list

```
[{"pk": 4, "model": "api.post", "fields": {"summary": "Testing", "title": "My Test"}}, {"pk": 5, "model": "api.post", "fields": {"summary": "testing again", "title": "Another test"}}]
```

But desired list is

```
[{"pk": 4,"summary": "Testing", "title": "My Test"}, {"pk": 5,"summary": "testing again", "title": "Another test"}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

django-jsonify is just a thin wrapper around Django's builtin JSON model serializer. See:

https://bitbucket.org/marltu/django-jsonify/src/586ff1bbdd9b1c20e450015a093c146e58d40ddb/jsonify/templatetags/jsonify.py?at=default

If you want a different format, you'll have to define your own serializer. To do so, subclass the stdlib's json.JSONEncoder, and override the .default() method:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.default

You'll also need to hook up your own template tag (or pass the JSON via the view, etc) - but, as you can see in the django-jsonify source, that part isn't very much code.

Comment: I have decided to use backbone with tastypie to fetch data